# Alternative Java code formatter for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, formatter

I am looking for alternatives to the Eclipse built-in Java code formatter. Not stand-alone, but for use from within Eclipse.

Any recommendations?

The default formatter is very powerful, I know. But still, maybe there are other powerful formatters out there.

Thanks!

Comment: And what features exactly are you missing?

Comment: What exactly means more powerful? What functionality do you exactly need? "One Formatter to rule them all, One Formatter to find them,
One Formatter to bring them all and in the darkness bind them"

Comment: @fiction would that be static or dynamic binding?

Comment: I am just looking for recommendations of alternatives to the Eclipse built-in Java code formatter. Any recommendation you can make is appreciated! From googling, I don't think there will be so many recommendations that we can be picky about individual features.

Comment: I hope you have explored the possibilities you have to configure the built in code formatter before dismissing it. Window - preferences, Java - Code Style - Formatter

Comment: @Fredrik Yes I did, and I like it. I am trying hard not to start a flame war over which one is the better formatter. I am merely just trying to compile a list of what's out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to work in a place when pointy haired bosses forced us to use [Jalopy Source Code Formatter](http://www.triemax.com/). There is also an [open source version somewhere on GitHub](https://github.com/notzippy/JALOPY2-MAIN). I can't say it was more/less powerful than eclipse, just another.
I switched back to eclipse as fast as I could.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Are there others?

Answer (score 0):

I just found [JIndent](http://www.jindent.com/) to add to the list. Didn't check its feature list yet though.